# Converting the equation $\theta = 5 \pi$ from polar into rectangular coordinates.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Converting the equation $\theta = 5 \pi$ from polar into rectangular coordinates.

The answer key says that turning this equation into rectangular coordinates should yield the question $y=0$. Can somebody help me understand why this is?

So, using the equation, we can see that $tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})=\theta=5 \pi$... But $y=0$ yields:

$tan^{-1}(0)=0 \neq 5\pi$

So I am confused.

I appreciate the help! Thanks!

Comment: You may want to write "Cartesian" instead of "rectangular"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cartesian coordinates are

$$x= r\cos(5\pi)= -r \le 0,\>\>\>\>\> y= r\sin(5\pi) = 0$$

which represents the negative $x$ axis.

Answer (score 3):

In polar coordinates the angle $5\pi$ corresponds to $\pi$ and therefore the equation $\theta =5\pi$ represents the negative side of the $x$ axis.

Indeed recall that $r\in[0,\infty)$ therefore for any fixed $\theta_0$ the equation $\theta =\theta_0$ represents an half-line (i.e. a ray) from the origin to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answer, the set $\{(r,\theta)  : \theta=5\pi\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is identically the set $\{(x,y)  : x<0, \; y=0\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. This is not actually the same as the set $\{(x,y)  : y=0\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ which is what you say the answer is